# missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

I just started using SQL, when I tried to run this code below, it showed error "missing right parenthesis"

```
SELECT a.author
FROM DLESSA.DBLP_AUTHOR a
WHERE a.authorId IN
(SELECT ea.authorId
FROM DLESSA.DBLP_ENTITY_ARTICLE ea
WHERE ea.entityId IN
(SELECT ea.entityId     
FROM DBLP_ENTITY_ARTICLE ea JOIN DBLP_ENTITY_AUTHOR ea1 ON    ea1.entityId=ea.entityId    ea1 JOIN DLESSA.DBLP_AUTHOR a ON a.authorId=ea1.authorId ea
WHERE ea.Author LIKE 'Tongs%'));
```

can someone tell me where my bug is? millions of thanks!

Comment: The particular snippet you've posted here is missing no parenthesis (unless your database system's SQL flavour requires enclosing joins in parentheses, which is not what you are asking, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Formatting reveals the cause:

```
SELECT a.author
FROM DLESSA.DBLP_AUTHOR a
WHERE a.authorId IN
    ( SELECT ea.authorId
      FROM DLESSA.DBLP_ENTITY_ARTICLE ea
      WHERE ea.entityId IN
          ( SELECT ea.entityId     
            FROM DBLP_ENTITY_ARTICLE ea            
              JOIN DBLP_ENTITY_AUTHOR ea1 
                ON    ea1.entityId=ea.entityId    ea1     ---  aliases?
              JOIN DLESSA.DBLP_AUTHOR a 
                ON a.authorId=ea1.authorId ea             --- here?
            WHERE ea.Author LIKE 'Tongs%'
          )
     );
```